# category description in single.php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

any ideas.

this works fine in category.php `<?php echo category_description(the_category_id()); ?>`

but it does not work in single.php, just the category id shows up not the description.

any ideas, how to get this done?

thanks in advance

edited:

Comment: what happens when you put that php code on the single.php page?

Comment: just the cat id shows up. not the description. same to you?

Comment: I'm not familiar with wordpress myself but have you tried looking at what those functions do?  or what the_category_id() returns?  I'd start by checking out those functions to see how they work.

Comment: i would suspect `the_category_id` returns `the category id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the_category_id()
```

has been  deprecated. 
This should work instead.

```
$category = get_the_category();
echo category_description($category[0]->cat_ID);
```

Comment: that is a clean code thanks @jack. here is a longer version answer i got in wp stackexchange. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/echo-category-description-in-single-php/5948#5948 thanks very much. appreciate both.

Comment: Let me encourage you to come answer questions over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com too. Since I didn't find you in the user list there so I assume you've not joined yet? We could use more good people people to answer questions, and it's still possible there to get listed on the first page of the reputation ranking *(which is effectively impossible here on SO!)*

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$category = $category->cat_ID;
```

To get current category ID, then echo the description

```
echo category_description($category);
```

This was used on Archive page (Category page) as at the time of running the code.

For a shorter version:

```
echo category_description(get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->cat_ID);
```